# Solicitud de memoria

Tags: c, linux, manejo-de-memoria

Les cuento mi duda. Tengo un sencillo programa en C, estoy trabjando con linux Mint. Lo unico que hace es pedir memoria hasta que no pueda pedir mas. Ahi les pongo el codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){


    printf("Iniciando creacion de matrices...\n");      

    double *p;
    int i=1;
    int cuenta=0;
    long int total;
    //printf("%lu",sizeof(double));
    while(i){
        p=malloc(10000*40000*sizeof(double));
        cuenta++;
        if(p==NULL){
            printf("ERROR %d \n",cuenta);
            break;
        }else{
            printf("CORRECTO %d \n",cuenta);
        }
    }
    total=(long int)10000*40000*cuenta;
    printf("%ld\n",total);
    printf("Listo\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Lo ejecuto una y otra vez. Segun mi interpretacion, como la memoria nunca es liberada, esta quedara ocupada y a la siguiente ejecucion no podria realizarse la asignacion de memoria pues ya habría asignado la memoria en la ejecución anterior y esta seguiría ocupada. Pero esto no es así, puedo ejecutarlo y ejecutarlo, y el valor de la variable cuenta es siempre el mismo: es decir siempre hace alrededor de 43980 asignaciones.

Bueno este código es solo una prueba de una duda que me surgió al hacer grandes asignaciones de memoria. Pero mi curiosidad básicamente se puede encontrar en el código.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: si realmente quieres explotar al procesador usa una funcion recursiva o aprende algebra booleana y usa bitwise operators

Answer (score 0):

En esta sección:

```
while(i) {
    p = malloc(10000 * 40000 * sizeof(double));
    cuenta++;

    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR %d \n",cuenta);
        break;
    } else
        printf("CORRECTO %d \n",cuenta);
}
```

Lo que estas haciendo básicamente es asignarle a la variable `p` la dirección de memoria que estas reservando con `malloc`, entonces en la primera iteración a `p` le asignas la dirección de un bloque de memoria (que reservas con `malloc`), en la segunda iteración a `p` le asignas la dirección de otro bloque de memoria (que reservas con `malloc`) y así sucesivamente hasta que `p` te de `NULL`, lo cual considerando el código que pusiste solo ocurrirá cuando ya no exista más memoria que puedas reservar, pero esto no tienen que ocurrir necesariamente en la segunda iteración.

**Ejemplo**

Por si no me di a entender bien, imagínate que tu memoria es como una tabla de ajedrez y en cada iteración de tu `while` estas reservando una celda con `malloc` y la dirección de esa celda se la asignas a `p`, en la segunda iteración vuelves a reservar otra celda (no puedes reservar la misma celda, ya que ya estaba reservada y no la liberaste, entonces `malloc` te asigna otra celda del tablero) y le vuelves a asignar la dirección de esa celda a `p`, esto continuara hasta que ya no queden más celdas disponibles que puedas reservar.